# Laravel Migration Showing Blank Page, No Debug Screen

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-4

I have a site in Laravel that's working perfectly fine here:

http://beta.modernassemb.ly

but when I try and move it to:

http://modernassemb.ly, it just shows a blank screen (everything is the same)

I'm not even sure how to go about debugging this, as the standard debug screen doesn't come up.  The error log just shows:

`[Mon Jun 16 00:36:56 2014] [error] [client 222.239.78.246] File does not exist: /var/www/198.211.105.63`

Where the IP `198.211.105.63` is the IP of the site.

When I echo statements in the index controller, they show up, but the templates/views aren't obviously rendering.

The paths on the server are:

**working:** `/var/www/beta.modernassemb.ly/public_html`

**not working:** `/var/www/modernassemb.ly/public_html`

I tried setting up a softlink so `/var/www/198.211.105.63` points to `/var/www/modernassemb.ly` to no avail.

And this is what my apache config file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName modernassemb.ly
        VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0/public_html
        ServerAlias *.modernassemb.ly

        DocumentRoot /var/www/

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.modernassemb\.ly$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://modernassemb.ly$1 [R=301,L]


        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride all
        </Directory>
        <Directory "/var/www">
                Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Please help as this is driving me crazy!!

Answer (score 0):

`chmod -R 777 app/storage` fixed it (transferring files didn't transfer folder permissions).  Wish the error messaging was a bit better!

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5 new file structure **storage/** folder is outside the **app/** folder

```
$ sudo chmod -R o+w storage/
```