# laravel returning blank screen in production environment

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I built a laravel application and uploaded via FTP
Its showing blank in cPanel hosting

I moved the laravel files to another folder and moved all "public" files to public_html folder
I made the app/storage flder writable.

After everything, it shows blank screen

Comment: turn on error reporting.

Comment: Debug = true already. But not showing anything

Comment: Have you uploaded your `vendor` folder?

Comment: @Marwelln Yes.
inside /laravel directory and pasted "public" files inside public_html

Comment: Maybe your htaccess is messed up and not redirecting properly? Also, try `composer dump-autoload` .

Comment: @YasenSlavov Yes tried it too.
Its showing blank.
is there any special settings needed for production environment?

Comment: Delete everything and replace with a `phpinfo()` index.php page and check your server is configured correctly for PHP?

Comment: @Lee Yes. it works fine. but still blank screen

Comment: make sure that you upload everything: I had troubles with FTP (didn't upload all files) before uploading also run composer with `--prefer-dist` and `--optimize-autoload` tell admins (server admins) to change root to `/www/public` instead of just `/www`

Answer (score 1):

I remember encountering this White Screen Of Death in one of my first attempts at Laravel. It was a permission issue. To avoid duplicate threads, here's a link outlining the issue and solution: [Laravel Migration Showing Blank Page, No Debug Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24252478/laravel-migration-showing-blank-page-no-debug-screen)

Comment: Yes. I made it 777. Then also same issues :-(

Answer (score 0):

Did you debugged if you get any output, for example try adding this to your routes.php file:

```
Route::get('/', function()  {
    dd('hi');
});
```

For Lavarel 4.2, this could also help:

```
php artisan optimize
```

Comment: The route is not working. The problem seems to be at the app starting.